# Toggle one <div> and close another?

Tags: jquery, toggle

I just started practicing jQuery and wrote this little snippet to open a dropdown on a menu entry. The problem is that I'd like to close the active one if I open another dropdown.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".dropdown").click(function(){ 
    $(this).children(".hidden").slideToggle(300);
  });
});
```

How to extend that code?

Regards
Patrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could select all the dropdown elements except for the one that was clicked (by negating `this` using the [`.not()` method](http://api.jquery.com/not/)) and then call the `.slideUp()` method on the child `.hidden` element:

```
$(".dropdown").click(function(){
  $(".dropdown").not(this).children(".hidden").slideUp();
  $(this).children(".hidden").slideToggle(300);
});
```

Here is a basic example:

```js
$(".dropdown").click(function(){
  $(".dropdown").not(this).children(".hidden").slideUp();
  $(this).children(".hidden").slideToggle(300);
});
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button>Dropdown</button>
  <div class="hidden">Some hidden dropdown menu</div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button>Dropdown</button>
  <div class="hidden">Some hidden dropdown menu</div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button>Dropdown</button>
  <div class="hidden">Some hidden dropdown menu</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you that was really helpful!